# Is it possible to receive the same message on two clients?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

We have one event producer and two clients (two different applications). These two clients have different roles but must receive the same events (order does not matter) from the same queue.

And I faced that a message will be consumed by only one client. Is it possible to receive the same message on two clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple and effective solution to address this requirement is to use a bridge.

Basically you would bridge the queue used by the producer to another queue and you would have one client using the main queue and the other using the bridged queue.

For details you can check EMS documentation :
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.6.0/doc/html/GUID-174DF38C-4FDA-445C-BF05-0C6E93B20189.html